# Amazon AWS Instalar PostgreSQL en mi EC2 o crear servicio separado de RDS?

Tags: postgresql, ec2, aws

Actualmente tengo un Web Service y una Base de datos en PosgreSQL los cuales necesito que esten en la nube, tengo una instancia EC2 en donde tengo tomcat instaldo, Quiero saber que me remiendan, tener el la base de datos en la instacia EC2 o hacerme del servicio RDS y tener la DB por apárte.

cual de las dos formas me recomiendan y por que?

Comment: Hola Leonardo, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Con respecto a tu pregunta te diré que como ignoramos las particularidades de tu caso, tus expectativas, requisitos, necesidades, requisitos y recursos, solo recibirías suposiciones u opiniones, algo que en la comunidad tratamos de evitar. Te recomiendo que sigas esta guía al editar tu pregunta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Leonardo Incluso si se intentara responder a tu pregunta, no estás brindando ninguna información que permita dimensionar tu estructura planteada, ni entender con qué frecuencia se utilizaría. Así como está planteada, las posibles respuestas son meras opiniones sin fundamento. Quizás convendría hace el ejercicio de ponerse en el lugar de alguien que quiera contestar. ¿No crees que le faltan datos para contestar algo concreto que sea más que una simple opinión?